# How to move the QGIS Layerpanel/Dockwidget programmatically

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqgis, legend, gui, qt

i'm working on a QGIS-plugin and want to move the default LayerPanel/Dockwidget to somewhere else programmatically. More specific: i want to move it into a tab of my tabwidget.
Is this possible? How can i get access to that specic dockwidget out of python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`qgis.utils.iface.mainWindow()` has `findChild` and `findChildren` methods.

Unfortunately the QDockWidgets that display a title of "Layers" and "Layer Order" *both* have an objectName of "Legend".

This code will gain access to the right widget:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

layersDockWidget = None
legendDockWidgets = qgis.utils.iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget, "Legend")
for dockWidget in legendDockWidgets:
  if dockWidget.windowTitle() == "Layers":
    layersDockWidget = dockWidget
    break
```

It can then be placed by calling `addWidget` on any `QLayout`.